# Javascript добавление поля формы - ОК, удаление не идет

Tags: javascript

Есть простая функция добавления поля формы, работает ОК.

Добавил ей кнопку удаления у добавленного элемента по ID в div'е. Однако удаление не происходит, выводит ошибку. Синтаксис проверил - вроде ошибок нет, а что не так, не пойму.

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```js
function btnDelete(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).remove();
}

function newInputAdd(id) {
  var y = 1;
  var newId = id + y;
  var firstform = document.getElementById('addfrm0');
  var newinput = document.createElement('input');
  var br = document.createElement("br");
  var btnDelete = '<input type="submit" onclick="btnDelete(b0f_' + newId + ')" value="x">';
  newinput.type = "file";
  newinput.name = "block[file][" + newId + "]";
  firstform.appendChild(newinput);
  firstform.appendChild(br);
  newinput.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", '<div id="b0f_' + newId + '">');
  newinput.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", "<span style='color:red'>" + newId + ".</span> ");
  newinput.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", btnDelete);
  newinput.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "</div>");

  if (newId > 9) {
    var newAdd = '';
  } else {
    var newAdd = '<input type="submit" onclick="newInputAdd(' + newId + ')" value="+">';
  }
  document.getElementById('bntAddPhoto').innerHTML = newAdd;
}
```

```html
<table border=0 width="100%">
  <tr class="odd">
    <td valign="top" width="200">
      Фото:
      <div id="addfrm0"></div>
      <div id="bntAddPhoto"><input type="submit" onclick="newInputAdd(0)" value="+"></div><br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: на данном ресурсе не решают задачи за автора, а **помогают** решить. алгоритм может быть следующий, создаете элемент(кнопка например), на нее вешаете обработчик клика по которому удаляете из дома ненужный элемент

Comment: Спасибо! Пробую добавить кнопку, но она не выводится, вот и написал без своего куска кода

Comment: для чего вы создаете **пустой** `div` с id? если в него поместить элементы создаваемые скриптом, то тогда удаление будет происходить просто, иначе вам нужен идентификатор для генерируемых элементов что бы по клику по кнопке удаление вы могли из обработчика найти эти элементы и удалить их

Comment: Да, спасибо за комментарий, не правильно задавал div с id, не знал что это можно сделать задав атрибут. Выложил исправленную версию, теперь все работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен, вдруг кому это пригодится - добавление и удаление поля формы на javascript

```
<h1>Форма</h1>

<input type="hidden" id="count" value="1">
<table border=0 id="upload_blocks" width="100%">
    <tr class="odd">
        <td valign="top" width="200">
            Фото: <div id="addfrm0"></div>
            <div id="bntAddPhoto"><input type="submit" onclick="newInputAdd(0);" value="+"></div><br>
        </td>
    </tr>                   
</table>

<script>
    function btnDelete(id){
        var div = document.getElementById(id);
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);

        var count = parseInt(document.getElementById("count").value);
        document.getElementById('count').value = count-1;


        if(count < 12){
            var newAdd = '<input type="submit" onclick="newInputAdd('+count+')" value="+">';
        }
        document.getElementById('bntAddPhoto').innerHTML = newAdd;


    }

    function newInputAdd(id) {
        var count = parseInt(document.getElementById("count").value);
        var newId = count;  
        document.getElementById('count').value = count+1;
        var firstform = document.getElementById('addfrm0');

        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute("id", "b0f_"+newId);
        div.innerHTML = '<span style="color:red">'+newId+'. </span><input type="submit" onclick="btnDelete(\'b0f_'+newId+'\')" value="x"><input type="file" name="block[file]['+newId+']"><br>';
        document.getElementById('addfrm0').appendChild(div);
      if(newId > 9){
        var newAdd = '';
      }else{
        var newAdd = '<input type="submit" onclick="newInputAdd('+newId+')" value="+">';
      }
      document.getElementById('bntAddPhoto').innerHTML = newAdd;
    }   
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var btnDelete = '<input type="button" onclick="btnDelete(\'b0f_'+newId+'\')" value="x">';
```

Comment: спасибо! так удаляется див с этим именем, но что-то он у меня раньше кнопки закрывается и в итогде она не пропадает, разбираюсь